# Executable not working in cross-platform as claimed

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I have used cx_Freeze to make `.exe` of my python app. It was build in windows 10 but it is not working in windows 7. But everyone is suggesting cx_freeze for having cross platform compatibility. The error I am getting while running is `api-ms-win-crt-runtine-l1-1-0.dll is missing in your computer`. What is the reason? Even for pyinstaller I got the same error.

I need to make `.exe` compatible with any windows platform. What are my options?

Comment: me too facing this problem for hours searching this forum. none of them works as a standalone exe without python on target machine. ESPECIALLY on windows 7. my OSX works fine tho

Comment: I just used pyinstaller. and it worked in all windows platforms for me. Actually I fixed this error why installing https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: turns out compiling python 3.8 is the problem for me. win 7 sp1 cant run python 3.8